# React native render from props

Tags: react-native

I have a very simple question but I cannot make it work. I'm making a new component and I want to pass content by props. I have the following code:

```
<FlatList
data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}]}
renderItem={
({item}) => <SwiperRow item={item} 
renderMain={({item})=><View style={{height: 60}}>
<Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Item Main
</Text></View>)}
/>
```

And SwiperRow has it code inside

```
<View style={[styles.main]}>
{this.props.rederMain}
</View>
```

But nothing is being render.
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `renderMain`:

```
<View style={[styles.main]}>
  {this.props.renderMain()}
</View>
```

so that it computes and returns the markup